# How to redirect audio from android device to bluetooth speeker

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, android-audiomanager

I am trying to redirect all the audio I play in my app to a bluetooth speaker. At first I pair the bluetooth device and then I try to 'say' to the audioManager, that all audio I play should be sent to the bluetooth speeker:

```
private final BluetoothAdapter _bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

public void pairBluetoothDevice(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice)
{
    BluetoothSocket socket= bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( UUID.fromString( "0000111E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" ) );
    socket.connect();

    _bluetoothAdapter.getProfileProxy( _appContext, _profileListener, BluetoothProfile.HEADSET );
}

private BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener _profileListener = new BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener()
{
  public void onServiceConnected( int profile, BluetoothProfile proxy )
  {
     if ( profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET )
     {
        _bluetoothHeadset = (BluetoothHeadset) proxy;
        _bluetoothHeadset.startVoiceRecognition(_device);

        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) _appContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        audioManager.startBluetoothSco();
        audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); 
     }
  }

  public void onServiceDisconnected( int profile )
  {
     if ( profile == BluetoothProfile.HEADSET )
     {
        AudioManager audioManager= (AudioManager) _appContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioManager.setBluetoothScoOn(false);
        audioManager.stopBluetoothSco();
        audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true); 

        _bluetoothHeadset.stopVoiceRecognition(_device);
        _bluetoothHeadset= null;
     }
  }
};
```

When I play audio ...

```
_soundPool.play( _soundPoolMap.get( index ), streamVolume, streamVolume, 1, 0, speed );
```

... I hear nothing.

Thanks for any hint :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the following workaround:
I open the default bluetooth settings where I can pair the bluetooth speaker and than the audio will be sent to the speaker automatically.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_BLUETOOTH_SETTINGS));
```